# How can I use the OFFSET worksheet function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a custom worksheet function that emulates the vlookup-match-offset combination and accepts only 3 arguments: the vertical lookup value, the horizontal lookup value, and the array containing the return values and header/left margin. If those values are represented by v, h, and r, I want the custom function to emulate:

```
=vlookup(v,r,match(h,offset(r,0,0,1),0),false)
```

The code I tried to write is as follows (using Excel 2010):

```
Function xlookup (v as Variant, h as Variant, r as Range) as Variant
    xlookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(v, r, _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(h, _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Offset(r,0,0,1),0),false)
```

Unfortunately, I don't think `Offset` is a method of `WorksheetFunction`. What's the best way to return the first row of a range as a range?

Comment: `Offset` is a built in `Range` object property. so you can directly apply it to your range. see my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. For my needs, Index works just fine.

```
Function xlookup(v As Variant, h As Variant, r As Range) As Variant
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        xlookup = .VLookup(v, r, .Match(h, .Index(r, 1, 0), 0), False)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Lovely! I have been looking for this for a long time.. And it works like charm. :)

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else is looking for an answer to this, the Excel Formula

```
OFFSET( A1, 1, 2, 3, 4 )
```

in VBA is

```
Range("A1").Resize(3, 4).Offset(1, 2)
```

---

In the question, `offset(r,0,0,1)` is just to get the first cell in a (column) range, so it can be simplified to `r(1)` in VBA.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done very simply with the Evaluate() function.

This evaluate function is super powerful. It can take your formula which you type into normal Excel and give you the answer straight away. For example, if you had a formula in a particular cell, for example, =sum(A1:A4), then in VBA you just go  Evaluate("=sum(A1:A4)")!

The one thing to be wary of is you need the right number of brackets otherwise it'll return #value